# Is there a way to list launch configurations sorted by CreatedTime via aws-cli?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, launch-configuration

I am finding a way on how to list launch configurations sorted by *CreatedTime*.
When I ran this command below, it does not return the oldest LC:

> aws autoscaling describe-launch-configurations --max-items 1

Is there a way for this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can control the the command's output using a [JMESPath](http://jmespath.org/) expression like this:

```
aws autoscaling describe-launch-configurations --query 'reverse(sort_by(LaunchConfigurations, &CreatedTime))'
```

The previous command will list all launch configurations ordered by descending `CreatedTime`. If you only want to get the latest launch config based on `CreatedTime`, add the `[0]` expression at the end of the command:

```
aws autoscaling describe-launch-configurations --query 'reverse(sort_by(LaunchConfigurations, &CreatedTime))[0]'
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked well. :)
Is there a way to check if the LC is attached to a ASG or unused?